# Syntax Error in C code

Tags: c, bubble-sort

```
void bubble (char cList[] ,int size)  {  // This is the line with the error
int swapped;
int p;
for (p = 1; p < size ; p++)
{
    swapped = 0;    /*this is to check if the array is already sorted*/
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < size - p; j++)
    {
        if(cList[j] > cList[j+1])
        {
            int temp = cList[j];
            cList[j] = cList[j+1];
            cList[j+1] = temp;
            swapped = 1;
        }
    }
    if(!swapped)
        {
        break; /*if it is sorted then stop*/
    }
}
}
```

This is a snippet of my code. `size` is a constant that I declared already. `cList` is an array of clients. I keep getting the error:

```
expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant
```

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: How did you declare `size`? using a `define`?

Comment: You said that `size` is a constant that I declared already... you cant then use `size` as a parameter to a function.

Comment: this program is in windows c...

Comment: @Hasturkun yes i used #define

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `size` is a macro defined as a constant, e.g. `

```
#define size 1234
```

then the code will read as, for example,

```
void bubble (char cList[] ,int 1234)  {
```

for which that is the correct error message.

To correct this, just remove the argument. Wherever `size` is seen the number will be substituted as a text change to the program before compilation. E.g.:

```
for (p = 1; p < size ; p++)
```

becomes

```
for (p = 1; p < 1234 ; p++)
```

**BONUS**

ALWAYS define numerical constants in brackets! It should read

```
#define size (1234)
```

See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#.23define

**BONUS BONUS**

Unless you have a good reason, it's best to use real constant variables, as Alexey Frunze says in the comment. Consider:

```
const int size = 1234;
```

Comment: A better approach could be to replace `#define size 1234` with `const int size = 1234;` and pass `size` into the function.

Comment: Certainly. I agree. But I am answering this particular question.

Comment: Great. If it solves your question, tick it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze would this still make size global and available to any module which it is called to?

Comment: If you want it to be local to this module, prepend `static`. Otherwise, it can be accessed from other modules.

Comment: I have gotten a new error... it says variably modified 'cList' at file scope. This happens at this line "struct client cList[size];" @AlexeyFrunze